# How can i combine fold effect with jQuery.remove()

Tags: jquery-ui

I want my div to fold first and then remove from the DOM. I tried this, but instead of folding first and then remove, it vanishes at once

```
$("#backgroundPopup").effect("fold", {

    size: "50%"

}, 1000).remove(); //end of effect()
```

If i just use

```
$("#backgroundPopup").effect("fold", {

    size: "50%"

}, 1000);
```

Then it folds but my div is still reside in the DOM. Can i combine both ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `effect`'s callback to `remove` the element.

```
$("#backgroundPopup").effect("fold", {
    size: "50%"
}, 1000, function(){
    $(this).remove();  // this will run after the effect is finished
});
```